# Add value to existing WP Block Editor setting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to add a 33% to the Wordpress Block "Button". So far it has 25%,50%,75% and 100%. Is it possible to insert my new value into the existing width selector?

I'm guessing **Block Filters** are the way to go.

I think I also found the way to get the settings object which might then help me to find out what I need to overwrite. However simply adding this code to my admin.js does not produce any output. **Where would I need to load this?**

```
const filterBlocks = (settings) => {
    if (settings.name !== 'core/buttons') {
        return settings
    }
    console.log(settings);
    return settings;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick solution:** Add a custom CSS class in the Buttons' block properties under *"Advanced > Additional CSS class(es)"* then define the custom width in your theme style.css

**Detailed solution:**
By using `wp.hooks.addFilter()` you can add a new control to the Button block with as many extra custom width options as you need.  The Button blocks preset widths are defined within the function `WidthPanel()` of the blocks [edit.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/button/edit.js#L48) function:

```
function WidthPanel( { selectedWidth, setAttributes } ) {
...
return (
    ...
        <ButtonGroup aria-label={ __( 'Button width' ) }>
            { [ 25, 50, 75, 100 ].map( ( widthValue ) => {
    ...
    }
}
```

To add a new width value of 33% to the block, we need to add our own new button control [to the InspectorControls](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) and then use `wp.hooks.addFilter()` to add this to the existing core Button block, eg:

**index.js**

```
import { createHigherOrderComponent } from '@wordpress/compose';
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, Button } from '@wordpress/components';

const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {

        const { setAttributes } = props;
        let widthValue = 33; // must be a number
    
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                <InspectorControls>
                     <PanelBody title="Custom Width">
                         <Button
                             key={widthValue}
                             isSmall
                             variant={widthValue}
                             onClick={() => setAttributes({ width: widthValue })}
                        >
                            {widthValue}%
                        </Button>
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, 'withInspectorControl');

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'core/button',
    withInspectorControls
);
```

Next, a new additional css style needs to be added that ([matches the existing width presets structure](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/button/style.scss)) for the new custom width, eg:

**style.scss**

```
$blocks-block__margin: 0.5em;

&.wp-block-button__width-33 {
    width: calc(33.33% - #{ $blocks-block__margin });
}
```

And there you have it..
[image: Custom Button Width on Button Block]

The easiest way to put all the code above together/working is to [create your own Gutenberg block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/tutorials/create-block/) (and that in itself can be challenging if you aren't familiar with the process or ReactJS). I too have come across similiar challenges with Gutenberg, so I wanted to provide a detailed solution for this kind of issue that works.